# Is it possible to remove nested directories "/runner_id/0/company_name" from a Gitlab CI build path?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an existing directory structure on a machine and want to configure Gitlab CI to clone/fetch repos to specific paths.

I've managed to change the builds_dir property in the config.toml file to start in the correct place, but Gitlab adds extra nested folders by default.

So I set:

```
builds_dir = "/Users/myUser/Development/projName"
```

and when Gitlab CI clones the repo, it adds

```
"/555555bb/0/orgName"
```

so I end up with:

```
"/Users/myUser/Development/projName/555555bb/0/orgName/projName"
```

Is there a way in the Gitlab config file to remove the extra sub-directories, or is my only option to move the files around after the clone/fetch is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Because of how Gitlab runners work you need to copy the files to the appropriate locations.

Since runners can handle multiple projects, they need to differentiate them in some way and this is where `/555555bb/0/orgName` part comes in.

You can define in your project-specific runner config where those files need to be copied to (a simple copy command will suffice).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a symbolic link between the repository used by the gitlab runner and the repository I am wishing to use for the deployment of the application.